# Tried making a button, that takes you to google page

Tags: javascript, html, css, xcode

i have a html script with button and onclick function script that should take me to google.com, but it doesn't seem to work. Been stuck with this for hours. Im also new to HTML.

Tried everything. Line 336 and 353 should be the needed content. And line 136 should be the button itself. I don't understand whats wrong. Anyone ever have had this issue?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon/text/javascript" href="https://static.codepen.io/assets/favicon/favicon-aec34940fbc1a6e787974dcd360f2c6b63348d4b1f4e06c77743096d55480f33.ico" />
<link rel="mask-icon" type="" href="https://static.codepen.io/assets/favicon/logo-pin-8f3771b1072e3c38bd662872f6b673a722f4b3ca2421637d5596661b4e2132cc.svg" color="#111" />
<title>SpyBanter - SpyBanter's Official WebSite</title>
<style type="text/css">
      body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
body:before {
  content: '';
  background: #c4252a url(http://subtlepatterns2015.subtlepatterns.netdna-cdn.com/patterns/cheap_diagonal_fabric.png);
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}

canvas {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 1s opacity cubic-bezier(0.55, 0, 0.1, 1);
}
canvas.ready {
  opacity: 0.4;
}

.intro {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 20px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fafafa;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 700px;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 0px 5px 20px black;
}
.intro h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
.intro p {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 24px;
}
#btnclose {
                background-color: indianred;
                border-color: darkred;
            }

            }
            #btnnup:hover, #btnsisu:hover, #btncmd:hover {
              background-color: #3e8e41;
            }
            #btnnup:active, #btnsisu:active, #btncmd:active {
              background-color: #3e8e41;
              box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
              transform: translateY(4px);
            }
            #btnsisu {
              left: 108px;
              top: 105px;
            }
            #btncmd {
              left: -311px;
              top: -88px;
            }
            #content {
              width: 100%;
              height: auto;
              min-height: 580px;
            }

    </style>
<script>
  window.console = window.console || function(t) {};
</script>
<script>
  if (document.location.search.match(/type=embed/gi)) {
    window.parent.postMessage("resize", "*");
  }
</script>
</head>
<body translate="no">
<canvas id="canvas" data-image="http://unsplash.it/g/450/200/?random=1"></canvas>
<div class="intro">
<h1>Interactive mosaic background</h1>
<p>Had to do this effect in a recent project and wanted to share it with you :). To change the background, edit the data-image on the canvas tag. You can also change the magnet effect intensity by changing the magnet variable</p>
<button id="btncmd">Videos</button>
</div>
<script src="https://static.codepen.io/assets/common/stopExecutionOnTimeout-de7e2ef6bfefd24b79a3f68b414b87b8db5b08439cac3f1012092b2290c719cd.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript">
      (function () {
  // Variables
  var Photo, addListeners, canvas, createGrid, ctx, gridItem, grids, height, img, imgInfo, imgSrc, imgs, init, magnet, mouse, populateCanvas, render, resizeCanvas, rotateAndPaintImage, updateMouse, useGrid, width;

  canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  width = canvas.width = window.innerWidth;

  height = canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

  imgSrc = canvas.dataset.image;

  img = new Image();

  useGrid = true;

  imgInfo = {};

  imgs = [];

  grids = [];

  magnet = 2000;

  mouse = {
    x: 1,
    y: 0 };


  init = function () {
    addListeners();
    img.onload = function (e) {
      var numberToShow;
      // Check for firefox. 
      imgInfo.width = e.path ? e.path[0].width : e.target.width;
      imgInfo.height = e.path ? e.path[0].height : e.target.height;
      numberToShow = Math.ceil(window.innerWidth / imgInfo.width) * Math.ceil(window.innerHeight / imgInfo.height);
      if (useGrid) {
        createGrid();
      }
      populateCanvas(numberToShow * 4);
      canvas.classList.add('ready');
      return render();
    };
    return img.src = imgSrc;
  };

  addListeners = function () {
    window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas);
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', updateMouse);
    return window.addEventListener('touchmove', updateMouse);
  };

  updateMouse = function (e) {
    mouse.x = e.clientX;
    return mouse.y = e.clientY;
  };

  resizeCanvas = function () {
    width = canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    return height = canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  };

  populateCanvas = function (nb) {
    var i, p, results;
    i = 0;
    results = [];
    while (i <= nb) {
      p = new Photo();
      imgs.push(p);
      results.push(i++);
    }
    return results;
  };

  createGrid = function () {
    var c, grid, i, imgScale, item, j, k, l, r, ref, ref1, ref2, results, x, y;
    imgScale = 0.5;
    grid = {
      row: Math.ceil(window.innerWidth / (imgInfo.width * imgScale)),
      cols: Math.ceil(window.innerHeight / (imgInfo.height * imgScale)),
      rowWidth: imgInfo.width * imgScale,
      colHeight: imgInfo.height * imgScale };

    for (r = j = 0, ref = grid.row; 0 <= ref ? j < ref : j > ref; r = 0 <= ref ? ++j : --j) {
      x = r * grid.rowWidth;
      for (c = k = 0, ref1 = grid.cols; 0 <= ref1 ? k < ref1 : k > ref1; c = 0 <= ref1 ? ++k : --k) {
        y = c * grid.colHeight;
        item = new gridItem(x, y, grid.rowWidth, grid.colHeight);
        grids.push(item);
      }
    }
    results = [];
    for (i = l = 0, ref2 = grids.length; 0 <= ref2 ? l < ref2 : l > ref2; i = 0 <= ref2 ? ++l : --l) {
      results.push(grids[i].draw());
    }
    return results;
  };

  gridItem = function (x = 0, y = 0, w, h) {
    this.draw = function () {
      ctx.drawImage(img, x, y, w, h);
    };
  };

  Photo = function () {
    var TO_RADIANS, finalX, finalY, forceX, forceY, h, r, seed, w, x, y;
    seed = Math.random() * (2.5 - 0.7) + 0.7;
    w = imgInfo.width / seed;
    h = imgInfo.height / seed;
    x = window.innerWidth * Math.random();
    finalX = x;
    y = window.innerHeight * Math.random();
    finalY = y;
    console.log(`INIT Y :: ${finalY} || INIT X :: ${finalX}`);
    r = Math.random() * (180 - -180) + -180;
    forceX = 0;
    forceY = 0;
    TO_RADIANS = Math.PI / 180;
    this.update = function () {
      var distance, dx, dy, powerX, powerY, x0, x1, y0, y1;
      x0 = x;
      y0 = y;
      x1 = mouse.x;
      y1 = mouse.y;
      dx = x1 - x0;
      dy = y1 - y0;
      distance = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
      powerX = x0 - dx / distance * magnet / distance;
      powerY = y0 - dy / distance * magnet / distance;
      forceX = (forceX + (finalX - x0) / 2) / 2.1;
      forceY = (forceY + (finalY - y0) / 2) / 2.2;
      x = powerX + forceX;
      y = powerY + forceY;
    };
    this.draw = function () {
      return rotateAndPaintImage(ctx, img, r * TO_RADIANS, x, y, w / 2, h / 2, w, h);
    };
  };

  rotateAndPaintImage = function (context, image, angle, positionX, positionY, axisX, axisY, widthX, widthY) {
    context.translate(positionX, positionY);
    context.rotate(angle);
    context.drawImage(image, -axisX, -axisY, widthX, widthY);
    context.rotate(-angle);
    return context.translate(-positionX, -positionY);
  };

  render = function () {
    var x, y;
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    while (y < grids.length) {
      grids[y].draw();
      y++;
    }
    while (x < imgs.length) {
      imgs[x].update();
      imgs[x].draw();
      x++;
    }
    return requestAnimationFrame(render);
  };

  init();

}).call(this);


  cmd = function () {
    window.location.href = "https://www.google.com/";           
  }
  function cmd() {
    window.location.href = "https://www.google.com/";               
  }
    btnclose.onclick = cmd;
    btnnup.onclick = cmd;
    btncmd.onclick = cmd;
//# sourceURL=coffeescript
      //# sourceURL=pen.js
    </script>
        <script type="application/javascript">
            window.onload = function() {
                main.style.opacity = "1";   
            }
            function show(){
                main.style.opacity = "1";   
            }
            function close() {
                main.style.opacity = "0";   
                $.post('http://tt_help/close', JSON.stringify({
                }));
            }
            function cmd() {
                window.location.href = "https://www.google.com/";               
            }
            function sisukord() {
              let id = $(this).attr('content');
              console.log(id)
              let docs = `https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vSXxzowHucTNRBwduXT-pDoGQT4blGJhOvgnzIYmpEe2DwU4mimf84RZ8orvUGpm2vPsPDdkkVAnFkq/pub?embedded=true${id}`;

              $('#main iframe').attr('src', docs);

            }
            window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
                if (event.data.type == "open") {
                    main.style.opacity = "1";                   
                }
            });
            btnclose.onclick = cmd;
            btncmd.onclick = cmd;
            btnsisu.onclick = cmd;
        </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Could you please reduce the code to a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to make a button that takes you to google.com, I would advise you to use an a tag, not a button tag. The tag automatically links you to your desired destination when clicked.

Example:

```html
<a href="https://www.example.com/"> Example </a>
```

If you want the link to look like a button, then simply look at the css options. I would advise you to look here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp

```css
a {
    background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom, lightblue, aquamarine);
    padding:5px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
    padding-right:50px;
    padding-left:50px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size:25px;
    border-radius:5px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px green;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.example.com"> Example </a>
```

If you are determined to use a `<button>` tag, then all you need to do is *within* that button tag add an onclick attribute. So, you would change your code to `<button id="btncmd" onclick="cmd()">Videos</button>`.

Example of what you want:

```js
function cmd() {
        window.location.href = "https://www.example.com/"; // I'm using example but you can use google.
    }
```

```html
<button id="btncmd" onclick="cmd()">Videos</button>
```

Comment: Yeah that works, thanks. But still, i would like to make it a button tag, as in my code. The same button worked with another script, but not with this one for some reason.

Comment: @SpyBanter There you go, I offered another solution if you really desire to use a button tag instead. Hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

You did not define `btncmd`. Adding this line to your code solves the problem:

```
var btncmd = document.getElementById("btncmd");
```

Comment: Which line should i add this line exactly? Tried adding it between button, but didn't work for me.

Comment: Add it below the `<script>` tag immediately, i.e. not inside any block. For exmple, you can add it as line 105.